# how to unit test service stack and visual studio

Tags: servicestack

I create a service stack mvc template that include 4 project using visual studio 2013
 - Web application
 - .ServiceInterface
 -.ServiceModel
 =.Tests

I am trying to write unit test ,but when i click Test ->Run-> All Tests. It just said build success and nothing else.  I try go debug the test but it didn't hit the break point. Can you some give me step by step to do this?

Comment: You should put an example of your test code here. Maybe you are missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You need an NUnit Test Runner to run your NUnit tests. You can use the [NUnit Test Adapter](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/releases/tag/3.5.1) to run NUnit tests from within VS.NET or [NUnit Console Runner](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/releases/tag/3.5) to run your NUnit test .dll in a stand-alone Application outside of VS.NET.

My preference is to instead use the [NUnit Test Runner in ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html) which is seamlessly integrated within VS.NET.